# Domain misconfiguration when loggging in to Samba 4.5 AD DC

Tags: domain, samba, directory, samba4, controller

I have set up a Samba 4.5 as a Domain Controller, I have added to AD a Windows 10 computer and a Windows 7 computer and a user and I can login from the windows computer. Relevant info:

- My domain is samdom.example.com
- The netbios name is SAMDOM
- The server is dc.samdom.example.com
- The user name is user

The problem is that in order to login to windows I have to use EXAMPLE\user instead of SAMDOM\user. After I login to Windows using EXAMPLE\user I see my info as SAMDOM\user. If I lock the computer and I need to unlock, SAMDOM is what is showing as the domain on the Windows login screen. However, I have to force login with EXAMPLE\user in order to unlock.

So my question is this:
Is this a bug in Samba version 4.5.16-Debian that it expects a name that is one DNS level up or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Further to my original post:

I can login to the domain windows PC by entering any value for the domain EXCEPT the actual domain (netbios).

So I can login using XYZ\user or EXAMPLE\use. The only one that I cannot use to login is SAMDOM\user.



This is very strange and hope that someone else has experienced and has advice on what to do.

Comment: It seems to be a version problem. Version 4.5.16-Debian that comes with Stretch seems do have this issue. When I tried Buster and Version 4.9.5-Debian I no longer have this issue.